# Javascript conditoinal returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

There are all kinds of examples of functions returning "undefined" but I'm having trouble finding a reason why my JS conditional (which I have reduced to a simple IF...ELSE statement) is returning "undefined" in the console.

```
var blue = "color";
var green = "color";


if (blue = green) {
    console.log("success");
}
else {
    console.log("fail");
}
```

Can someone please explain what is undefined? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the console.log() return is `undefined`, not the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your if contains an assignment, not an equality check.

Replace:

```
blue = green
```

With:

```
blue == green
```

Or preferably:

```
blue === green
```

Since both are expected to be strings, you can (and should) use the strict equality check (`===`), there.

This "triple equals" check if both type and value are equal, compared to only value for the `==`:

```js
alert("1 === '1': " + (1 === '1'));
alert("1 == '1': " + (1 == '1'));
```

---

Now, if you run that code in a browser's console, the actual code will not return a value, thus, it will output `undefined`, aside from the `console.log()` results:

[image]

Comment: Never use double equals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: Never say _"Never"_. If you know what types you're comparing, and you're familiar with JS's type casting, a `==` really isn't that bad.

Comment: Really? 2 downvotes? What's so wrong about this answer?

Comment: You and me both @Cerbrus http://i.imgur.com/otKjoWr.png . I wish there were more explanations given at times.

Answer (score 1):

Your current if-statement is conducting an operation of setting blue to equal green. The single equals sign does not actually check for a truthy value.

In order to run a boolean check here, you need to use a triple equals operator.

```
if (blue === green)
```

If you run this in the console, here's how it looks:

[image]

Since your if statement doesn't actually return anything (instead, it just logs to the console), you will receive `undefined` as your output.

Comment: You may want to explain _why_.

Comment: This still results in undefined.

Comment: I just tested this in the console. The if statement, when run with the triple-equals, returns 'success'. Am I missing some vital part of OP's code that wasn't posted?

Comment: The if statement doesn 't return anything. Sure, `'success'` will be logged, but nothing's returned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, seriously appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you see undefined in the console is because that is what the executed code finished with. The last statement executed was the if else clause which has no return value, hence `undefined`.

A second important aspect to note is that you are doing an assignment inside of your if statement, and as a result of that assignment you are always going to end with `if( "color" )` which is going to always be true, and as a result the console.log will always occur.

This results in the console looking like

```
"success"
undefined
```

Since someone downvoted this and apparently is not familiar with executing console code

[image]